# Run button in xcode 7.1 is changed

Tags: xcode7.1

My run button in Xcode 7.1.1 has changed and now when I run , the UItests are running . Is there any way to revert it ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click and hold the run button for different run options.

Answer (score 0):

Once i closed and reopened Xcode the run button (which has changed to test button with no options showing up) has reverted .